# Transferring apps from 1st Gen ipod touch to another 1st Gen ipod touch?

Tags: ipod-touch, ipod, ipod.app

I've got a 1st generation ipod touch with a cracked screen and messed up Home button. There are certain apps on it (Tap Tap Revenge) that simply aren't available anymore. If I buy a new 1st generation ipod touch (or any generation, for that matter), is it possible to transfer the apps? I would assume iCloud doesn't work with first generation, but I don't really know.

Answer (score 1):

Does it still work, for a given value of 'work'? You need to at least be able to interact with it to some extent, otherwise you're stuck.

You will need an older version of iTunes, something earlier than 12.7, which dropped the saving of apps to the computer.

Here's a list of iTunes versions - [LifeWire: Where to Download Every Version of iTunes](https://www.lifewire.com/download-every-version-itunes-2000446). These are direct from Apple themselves. There's also a comprehensive a list of Windows downloads at [OldDownload](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/itunes/), though these are not Apple-hosted.

You would of course need an OS that can run those too. Apple really don't provide min/max OS details of which version works on what, they just assume you will always have 'the latest' of everything, so some trial & error might be necessary. You may even need to run an older macOS/OS X in VM. I think 12.6 will only run in High Sierra or earlier. idk about Windows versions.

Once armed with the correct older iTunes, you can then backup the old iPod & set up your 'new' one as a direct copy of the original, by using Restore.

Just for info, here's the spec for that iPod, on [EveryMac](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/ipod/specs/ipod-touch-specs.html)